# How big is the impact of accessing directly a property vs accessing a property through reflection?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

Suppose you have a class like the following:

```
public class Test
{
    public string prop {get;set;}
    public string prop2 {get;set;}
    public string prop3 {get;set;}
    public string prop4 {get;set;}
    public string prop5 {get;set;}
    public string prop6 {get;set;}
    public string prop7 {get;set;}
    public string prop8 {get;set;}
    public string prop9 {get;set;}
    public string prop10 {get;set;}
    public string prop11 {get;set;}
    public string prop12 {get;set;}
    public int count{get;set;}
}
```

I'm writing a method that need to takes at some points only 2-4 properties out of this class and then do some operation (which will be always the same, no matter which property is chosen). To avoid to basically copy/paste the same exact code multiple time (i.e. repeat the //do stuff section, for every switch case), i've written something like this:

```
    public static DataTable GetTop(currenctCondition)
    {
        DataTable res = null;
        List<Test> appo = GetAllTests();
        string[] propToGet = null;
        switch (currenctCondition)
        {
            case condition1:
                propToGet = new string[] { "prop1", "prop2" };
                break;
            case condition2:
                propToGet = new string[] { "prop3", "prop4" };
                break;
            case condition3:
                propToGet = new string[] { "prop5", "prop6" };
                break;
            case condition4:
                propToGet = new string[] { "prop7", "prop8", "prop9", "prop10" };
                break;
        }
        foreach(Test c in appo)
        {
            foreach(string prop in propToGet)
            {
                string ent = c.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetGetMethod().Invoke(c, null).ToString();
                // do stuff
            }

        }
        return res;
    }
```

basically, to make the code more readable and easy to maintein, i build an array of strings that contains the name of the property i have to access, and use the reflection to get the property value using :

```
string ent = c.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetGetMethod().Invoke(c, null).ToString();
```

Of course this is slower than accessing directly the property i need, but i wonder how big can be the impact of this choice. Consider that `List<Test> appo` can be super small but also very very big ranging from 0 to (possibly, in very rare cases) millions of element.

To get `appo` i need to do query on MySQL, so my theory is that this operation will always be more time consuming, making the performance loss using the reflection meaningless. I am going to try to test this, but the setup will cost me some time, so i would like to have some preliminary info from someone who has more experience than me in this field

Comment: The simplest way to speed it up is to create a map from property name to "a delegate to fetch the property". That avoids *most* of the reflection you're using there in a loop. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/ for some sample code. There are other options that require a bit more work, but just caching the delegate would speed things up enormously.

Comment: thank you @JonSkeet. I am going to read that and see how can improve my current code

Comment: @JonSkeet i have some problem on understanding how MethodInfo constructedHelper = genericHelper.MakeGenericMethod
            (typeof(T), method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType, method.ReturnType); works in your example

Comment: Without more information about in what *way* you don't understand it, I'm unlikely to be able to help explain it. But you may well not need all the complexity I showed in the blog post. Just the "Converting MethodInfo into a delegate instance" part is likely to be enough.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you can check the edit i explained my current problem. I am afraid that the "Converting MethodInfo into a delegate instance" is not enough

Comment: So to clarify, what happens if you run the code in "Creating open delegates with reflection"? Does that part work? If not, please give more details about the environment in which you're running.